One centralized class to wrap/manage OpenTelemetry
I am learning OpenTelemetry hands-on. I want to add OpenTelemetry manual instrumentation to my Java webapp, but I don't want to do import io.opentelemetry.api.* in every class file that needs instrumentation. Hence I created this wrapper/manager class.
package com.myorg.opentelemetry;

import io.opentelemetry.api.OpenTelemetry;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Span;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.StatusCode;
import io.opentelemetry.api.trace.Tracer;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.OpenTelemetrySdk;
import io.opentelemetry.sdk.trace.SdkTracerProvider;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

public class OpenTelemetryManager {

    private static OpenTelemetry openTelemetry;
    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, Span> spans = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public static void init() {
        openTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                .setTracerProvider((SdkTracerProvider) GlobalOpenTelemetry.getTracerProvider())
                .build();
    }

    public static void startSpan(String instrumentationName, String spanName) {
        Tracer tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer(instrumentationName);
        Span span = tracer.spanBuilder(spanName).startSpan();
        spans.put(spanName, span);
    }

    public static void endSpan(String spanName) {
        Span span = spans.remove(spanName);
        if (span != null) {
            span.end();
        }
    }

    public static void setSpanStatus(String spanName, StatusCode status) {
        Span span = spans.get(spanName);
        if (span != null) {
            span.setStatus(status);
        }
    }

    public static String getTraceId(String spanName) {
        Span span = spans.get(spanName);
        if (span != null) {
            return span.getSpanContext().getTraceId();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getSpanId(String spanName) {
        Span span = spans.get(spanName);
        if (span != null) {
            return span.getSpanContext().getSpanId();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Then any class that needs instrumentation should do the following:
import com.myorg.telemetry.OTelManager;

public class ExampleService {

    public void exampleMethod() {
        OTelManager.startSpan("exampleMethodSpan");
        try {
            // Your method logic here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            OTelManager.setSpanStatus("exampleMethodSpan", StatusCode.ERROR);
        } finally {
            OTelManager.endSpan("exampleMethodSpan");
        }
    }
}

I'm not sure whether I've covered all the necessary functions or use cases. This is currently in my branch code, but once this is working I would like to merge this into my master, so it has to be ready for a production environment as well.

Can different threads access the same span? For example, thread 1 starts span "abc", and thread 2 stops "abc"? Can it happen that two concurrent threads start/stop two different spans with the same name? What happens in that case?

@Green绿色 I'm not sure, is that a viable use case in OpenTelemetry? If it is then I'll have to cater for it

@Green绿色 I apologize if my answer seems vague; it's just that I'm still trying to understand how OTel works and my grasp of the underlying concepts is not strong.

I haven't used OpenTelemetry myself yet. You're using ConcurrentMap, so I expect that your code is multi-threaded (maybe a Web service?), and it's not uncommon for multiple threads to run the same tasks in parallel (e.g., HTTP request handlers in a Web service). If that's the case here, I think, you might prefer thread-local maps or ensure unique names instead to avoid your threads to mangle with each other's measurements. Besides, ConcurrentMap involves inter-thread synchronization, so it may have a (small) impact on your application's performance.

What you have done is a well known architectural structure, but probably not for the reasons it is usually done. Hiding a third party API behind an internal API is a way to isolate the dependency to the 3rd party API. If you need to change the telemetry library, you only have to change the implementation of the internal API instead of changing every single component that is being measured. Of course in this case I would not use "OpenTelemetry" in the class name as it then makes a suggestion about the underlying implementation. Other than that, Bobby's advice on the telemeletry tokens is good.

public class OpenTelemetryManager {

If this class is only used as static Utility, it should be final and have a private constructor:
public final class OpenTelemetryManager {
    private OpenTelemetryManager() {
    }

That way the class clearly indicates how it is supposed to be used.

    public static void init() {
        openTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                .setTracerProvider((SdkTracerProvider) GlobalOpenTelemetry.getTracerProvider())
                .build();
    }

init is not guarded against multiple (concurrent?) invocations. It should be, in the most simple case:
public static synchronized void init() {
    if (openTelemetry == null) {
        openTelemetry = OpenTelemetrySdk.builder()
                .setTracerProvider((SdkTracerProvider) GlobalOpenTelemetry.getTracerProvider())
                .build();
    } else {
        // TODO Optional throw error here.
    }
}


    public static void startSpan(String instrumentationName, String spanName) {
        Tracer tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer(instrumentationName);
        Span span = tracer.spanBuilder(spanName).startSpan();
        spans.put(spanName, span);
    }

startSpan is not guarded against multiple concurrent invocations either. If you have two threads doing the same thing, they will happily overwrite each other. The quickest way to fix that would be to make the spans-Map a ThreadLocal:
private static final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Span>> spans = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new HashMap<>());

public static void startSpan(String instrumentationName, String spanName) {
    Tracer tracer = openTelemetry.getTracer(instrumentationName);
    Span span = tracer.spanBuilder(spanName).startSpan();
    
    spans.get().put(spanName, span);
}

And so forth. So each Thread has its own Map and it cannot interfere with other Threads. The same goes for all other methods.

However, the approach to store everything in a global state can be cumbersome and error-prone and raises a few synchronization questions. Maybe another approach would be to use "measurement tokens" which act as local...uhhh...token.
Basically you create a small class which holds all the state in itself, and which you can then use to measure the method. Something like this for example (some pseudoish code):
public class Meter implements AutoCloseable {
    public Meter(Span span) {
        super();
        
        this.span = span;
    }

    public void end() {
        span.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        span.end();
    }
}

Implement AutoCloseable has the upside that you could surround blocks with try...catch with this class, if you want that.
Your example usage would become something like this:
public class ExampleService {

    public void exampleMethod() {
        Meter meter = OpenTelemetryManager.startMeter("exampleMethodSpan");
        try {
            // Your method logic here
        } catch (Exception e) {
            meter.setFailed();
        } finally {
            meter.end();
        }
    }
}

That has the upsides that:

The measurement itself only lives as long as the method that is being measured.
No global state. The utility class only returns a new instance and is done with that.
Concurrency/Multithreading is irrelevant.
You're not repeating (and potentially subsequently mistyping) the name of the measurement.
If you ever want to disable measuring (globally or only for certain names), you can easily do so by returning a "dummy" Meter instance.

Additional utility could be built around that concept, for example something like this:
OpenTelemetryManager.meter("name", () -> {
    // Your method logic here.
});


OTelManager

Do not shorten names just because you can. It makes the code harder to read, understand and maintain.

The telemetry tokens are a very good idea but I am not a fan of the lambda suggestion. It can be a handy tool but it makes the telemetry the main focus of the code. (I would most prefer an annotation driven telemetry framework to prevent the classes from being cluttered with non-functional code, but that's way beyond the scope of this review.)

An Annotation based approach has the downsides that you need a mechanic to scan all classes at runtime (or generate custom classes/code beforehand) and that splitting a single method into multiple measured operations is not possible. Though, one could argue that the last should be the default anyway, but we all know that that is easier said than done. I don't get the "makes the main focus of the code" argument though, it's just another tool used there.

What I meat with that the main purpose of the code becomes easier to miss because it's "hidden" in a telemetry operation, which makes the code harder to read. Also the execution of the business critical code is being controlled by an auxiliary tool, which provides the telemetry component the means to break the code it is measuring.
